# Unable to load a generic type into another AppDomain in ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, appdomain

I have a very odd problem where I am unable to load a generic type into another AppDomain when running inside of ASP.NET, but it works in my Test project and a Console app.

The relevant code does essentially this:

```
Assembly ass = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string AssemblyPath = ass.Location;

var templateType = typeof(RazorEngine<RazorTemplateBase>);

object instance = LocalAppDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(AssemblyPath,
                                             templateType.FullName)
                                .Unwrap();
```

The code bombs on the last line. The AppDomain exists and its base execution and bin paths are matched to the original AppDomain.

When running through this code in a test project, it works fine. The instance is created (as a TransparentProxy remoting reference) and all is well.

When running in ASP.NET I get a type error on the generic type parameter:

> GenericArguments[0], 'Westwind.RazorHosting.RazorTemplateBase', on
>   'Westwind.RazorHosting.RazorEngine`1[TBaseTemplateType]' violates the
>   constraint of type 'TBaseTemplateType'.

where TBaseTemplateType is the same type passed in (ie. RazorTemplateBase) with RazorEngine defined like this:

```
public class RazorEngine<TBaseTemplateType> : MarshalByRefObject
    where TBaseTemplateType : RazorTemplateBase
```

Clearly I'm passing the right type since it is the actual restraining type, but somehow the AppDomain is not recognizing the Generic type as the same.

As I mentioned it works inside of a Windows application and a test project, but inside of ASP.NET the generic type won't instantiate across AppDomain boundaries. Using the same code to create a non-generic type (even the same non-generic version of this type RazorHosting that inherits from RazorHosting) and it works fine.

Stumped. What could ASP.NET be doing to make this behave so differently than when running in a test project?

Comment: I think Russel is right. This is probably a shadow copying issue. Try to replace AssemblyPath with templateType.Assembly.Location.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this strange issue before.  It seems to come down to a combination of Shadow Copy (which ASP.NET uses by default), each AppDomain's ApplicationBase and Load Contexts.

It's been a while since I've had this problem in my brain but check out my answer to this question to see if that helps:

[Domain problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932370/how-do-i-pass-references-as-method-parameters-across-appdomains)